# How to remove session attribute for jsp page

Tags: java

I am setting ERROR_HOLDER in session attribute in Controller.And showing error message on Jsp,
 when i am coming back to same jsp page from other tab or jsp page.Error message is still showing their at jsp.But i want to remove that error message from jsp page when you come back  other page. 
I tried with remove attribut on jsp but it didn't work.

want to remove ERROR_HOLDERA from session once jsp page is display.

Comment: why dont you use request scope?

Comment: or if your requirement is to put in session then show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you are setting session variable in controller and controller is deciding which JSP to show, I assume you are using Spring framework.
Spring framework provides you `RedirectAttributes`, which you can use to pass variables to JSP which will be there for one request only. If you come again to same page or refresh it, you won't have access to those variables. Generally these are used to show error messages on pages. In such cased you don't need to store variables in session. Read links given below to understand more about it.

[Site 1](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/)

[Official Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Just use ERROR_HOLDER in request scope, if its state is not required later.
- Do not keep values in session if its value is not required over multiple requests.

Unnecessary usages will make things messy and memory overhead will become high